# How do I use the Crypto++ library within Eclipse? (C++)

Tags: c++, eclipse

I'm having trouble getting Crypto++ to work from within the C++ Eclipse IDE. I *think* I installed it correctly, but every time I try to do any sort of include in the file so I can use the new library, it does not compile. It will compile C++ normally, but it won't let me use the new library. (Bear in mind, I am not too familiar with this whole process with libraries as a whole.)

My process:

- Downloaded 7.0 from here: https://www.cryptopp.com/#download
- Unzipped it into a folder on my Desktop called Crypto++
- Created a new project, it compiled.
- Right click on new project, properties -> C/C++ Build -> settings ->
  Tool settings
- Clicked add, file system, and then clicked the folder I created, and
  hit apply.

So, it is listed under library search path, but this include does not work:

```
#include "cryptlib.h"
```

Did I install the library properly, or am I missing something?

**Edit:**

fatal error: cryptlib.h: No such file or directory

Comment: *it does not compile* not helpful clue.

Comment: Headed in the wrong direction, I think. Go to properties -> C/C++ General->Paths and Symbols and add the include folder path on the Includes tab, add any libraries (without the extension or any lib prefixes. Eg enter wtf if you want libwtf.a) to the Libraries Tab, and then add the path to the libraries to the Library Paths tab.